# Синхронизация строк в базе данных mySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы с одинаковым полем ID (по моему это называется связь один к одному). Эти поля связаны через связи. Данные добавляются в одну таблицу. Нужно, чтобы Этот ID сразу появлялся и в другой. Как это можно сделать, кроме очевидного сразу добавлять в две таблицы? Желательно средствами mySQL

Comment: А можете все же наглядно показать структуру таблицы 1 и 2. Показать что к чему относится.... и показать наглядно что куда вставляете и какой результат ожидаете?

Comment: Связи один к одному, да еще с автовставкой ... Интересно зачем такое вдруг понадобилось и не поменять ли что нибудь в архитектуре. Например собрать все в одной таблице ...

Comment: Это другой вопрос на самом деле. Мне тоже в голову приходило. Просто есть счетчик просмотров. Он обновляется регулярно. И есть поле с временем последнего обновления. И нежелательно, чтобы оно учитывало обновление счетчика (а это происходит). Поэтому решил вынести в другую таблицу. Если сможете в комменте посоветовать, как это обойти (и это не противоречит политики сайта), то был бы рад

Comment: Я так понимаю счетчик обновляется отдельным запросом, другие данные при этом не меняются ... и дата обновления - это видимо поле типа timestamp. Тогда счетчик обновляйте как то так `update table set counter=counter+x, tstamp=tstamp where ...`. Т.е. вы полю timestamp явно присваивайте его текущее значение, тогда оно не обновится :)

Comment: Спасибо, подумаю, как лучше)))) Может и правда все в одну сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте TRIGGER, который будет автоматический добавлять запись в другую таблицу.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_table AFTER INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO table_name_two VALUES (NEW.id)
```

А вообще правильно использовать несколько запросов на INSERT в пределах одной транзакции, что было бы удобно и очевидно для других разработчиков, которые будут поддерживать Ваш код. Потому что есть такая доля разработчиков, которые пихают все что только можно в хранимые процедуры и тригеры, а потом не разберешься почему выполняешь только этот запрос, а там еще 100500 блокировок где-то произошло и записей изменилось.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю. Но вы считаете, что лучше не усложнять и сделать двойной INSERT?

Comment: Да, нет ничего страшного в том, что вы в пределах одной транзакции выполняете два INSERT, если того требует ваша бизнес логика.

Comment: Уже прочел дополненный ответ) Спасибо. Но и за триггеры спасибо